# JavaScript - prerender another page

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I'm trying to make a simple gallery page. The website will always reload after pressing "Next" and I want to make some prerender for the next slide (for better performance and faster load).
At the moment I'm using prefetch/prerender options from HTML5, for Chrome and FireFox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="prefetch" href="index2.html">
        <link rel="prerender" href="index2.html">
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="big_big_buck_bunny.jpg"/>
        <a href="index2.html">Next</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any other way to cache/prerender next page (in this example - index2.html) ? For example using JavaScript? I'm asking about it because I want to make the prerender work also on Opera 12 and IE (8/9).

Comment: You could speed up rendering by putting an iFrame off the screen which points to the url.

Comment: Because of the adverts, I cant load the page using iFrame. iFrame loads everything (also js and css), so it will display adverts even when the iFrame is hidden (and users wont see them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use AJAX. In jquery exists .load() method (http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#next').click(function () {    
    $('#container').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/webdevem/JfcJp/show/');
});

$('#prev').click(function () {
    $('#container').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/webdevem/JfcJp/show/ #specialContent');
});
```

Here You have example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6Wf5/5/)

Comment: This is missing `preventDefault()`. It's not equivalent to a prerender since it only fetches the HTML page and not the resources it links to. Also, it only changes the HTML in #container and doesn't clear event listeners or run any Javascript that's waiting for DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score -1):

If your going to navigate to a new page there's no way to precache html. That's what Ajax is for.

You can Ajax in the html, set the document body to the new html. But if the use reloads the page it will be at the wrong place unless you set a #! In the URL. There's not a lot of nice options with IE8.

Answer (score -1):

Cant you see just preload the images, The page itself isnt gona take any time to build...is it?